# background transparency crossbrowser especially ie

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, transparency, stylesheet

I am having a huge problem figuring out how to use a transparent background color for my website. I can do it with the background:rgba style attribute which works for all browsers expect ie.  It very hard to do it in IE though.  You can use opacity or filter:alpha but this makes everything within the div transparent. I dont want that I only want the background color to be transparent.  How do I do this please help Ive been looking for explanations on the internet and cannot find a solution.

Comment: IE is unbelievably brain-damaged when it comes to handling 4-channel compositing.

Comment: i think you can simply put a transparent gif file as a background for your div.

Comment: @Coding-Freak I strongly suspect that the question concerns PNG backgrounds with alpha channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around this by layering two separate DIVs, one for the transparency and one for the actual content:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container .transparency {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: ...;
  opacity: ...;
  /* apply same width and height as parent DIV */
}

.container .content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  /* apply same width and height as parent DIV */
}
```

Comment: That works well if you can fix both heights. Alternatively, tweak both heights via JS so they match.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your background image's opacity to 50% with Photoshop and then use it.

If you want to change the opacity using Jquery or JavaScript you can change background image to opaque version of the same background image.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a large semi-transparent flat-color PNG for the IE part. Depending on how far back you need to go in terms of old IE versions, you may also have to use some JS to get the transparent PNG to work.